# React bootstrap modal menu approach?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Any idea how to create a dropdown menu that is a modal dialog? that is it's triggered by selecting a menubar the modal item is the dropdown that contains the options to select and it as an apply or close in it such that no other clicks outside of the dropdown are effective until your click on apply or close.

I'm using react-boostrap but the Modal component is not what I can use since it takes over the whole screen and renders the dialog box on top, is there a way to make the contents of a Modal relative to the menu?

Comment: By definition a modal takes the whole screen.. why not just use a normal dropdown for this and prevent outside clicks? or just show / hide a container or something.

Comment: @azium is there a way to prevent outside clicks from a react component?